# Saving Search List in Custom Object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a Custom Object with nothing but a VisualForce Page in it.  The purpose is for them to create a NEW record of search list.  That after they did their search and press save the next time they come back the list is still there.  So in the custom object you can have multiple records of list created.

Here is my problem.  Since the VisualForce page is in "Edit" mode as soon as you create a record.  Can I make a "SAVE" button so the list stays or save?

How can I write that code?  Thanks in advance

[image]

Here is my code

```
    <apex:page standardController="Seek_List__c" extensions="ContactSearchController" sidebar="true">

  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />

    <apex:pageBlock title="Find Me A Customer!" mode="edit">

  <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>  
    <td width="200" valign="top">

      <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function doSearch() {
        searchServer(
          document.getElementById("firstName").value,
          document.getElementById("lastName").value,
          document.getElementById("accountName").value,
          document.getElementById("technology").options[document.getElementById("technology").selectedIndex].value
          );
      }
      </script> 

      <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
          <apex:param name="firstName" value="" />
          <apex:param name="lastName" value="" />
          <apex:param name="accountName" value="" />
          <apex:param name="technology" value="" />
      </apex:actionFunction>

      <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">First Name<br/>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Last Name<br/>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Account<br/>
        <input type="text" id="accountName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Interested Technologies<br/>
          <select id="technology" onchange="doSearch();">
            <option value=""></option>
            <apex:repeat value="{!technologies}" var="tech">
              <option value="{!tech}">{!tech}</option>
            </apex:repeat>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>

      </apex:pageBlock>

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="results">

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="contact">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="First Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="firstName" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.firstName}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Last Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="lastName" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastName}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Account" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="account.name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.account.name}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Technologies" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="interested_technologies__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.interested_technologies__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <apex:pageBlock title="Debug - SOQL" id="debug">
      <apex:outputText value="{!debugSoql}" />           
  </apex:pageBlock>    

  </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: What fields have you created in your custom object select list?

Comment: no fields created on this particular custom object.  The page is accessing data from contacts.  I do want more options other than contacts.  I would like it to be be able to search on LEADS, Accounts and other Custom Objects.